# Problem with integration of React Drawer Navigation in React Native app

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have been trying to install Drawer Navigator from [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator) in a React Native app and after installing it using the following 2 commands from the docs:

`npm install @react-navigation/drawer`
`npx expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

and after adding them the app crashed and the instructor in the course i am learning from mentioned that there is a problem that will lead to this crash and advised to run the following command

`npm install react-native-reanimated@1 --save --save-exact`

to change the version of react-native-reanimated to version 1.

However, after doing the above mentioned instructions, I had the following Error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

and this is the error displayed in the emulator:

[unCaught Error on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4bMe.png)

after searching for solutions some mentioned that i need to add the following code to babel.config.js `plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],` but it did not work also

and following are babel.config.js, package.json and App.js codes for reference:

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  };
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-app-loading": "^2.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

App.js

```
// import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import CategoriesScreen from "./screens/CategoriesScreen";
import MealsOverviewScreen from "./screens/MealsOverviewScreen";
import MealDetailScreen from "./screens/MealDetailScreen";
import FavoritesScreen from "./screens/FavoritesScreen";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function DrawerNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Categories" component={CategoriesScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Favorites" component={FavoritesScreen} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar style="light" />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: "#351401" },
            headerTintColor: "white",
            contentStyle: { backgroundColor: "#3f2f25" },
          }}
        >
          <Stack.Screen
            name="DrawerScreen"
            component={DrawerNavigator}
            options={
              {
                // title: "All Categories",
              }
            }
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="MealsOverview" component={MealsOverviewScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="MealDetail" component={MealDetailScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

So how can i solve this issue?

I tried to add the following code to to babel.config.js file `plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"],`and it did not solve the problem.

Moreover, i tried to add the following 2 dependencies in package.json file

```
"@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.2.0"
  },
```

and this did not solve the problem also

Comment: After you add `plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"]` to babel.config.js you need to start expo with the cache clean (`expo start -c`). I think that v1 fix your instructor provided  is outdated. With [reanimated v3](https://blog.swmansion.com/announcing-reanimated-3-16167428c5f7) completely dropping support for v1, I dont think there would still be many libraries that would force you to use v1. The accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76304531/convert-reanimated-v1-math-to-v3) shows how much easier v2 to is to use than v1.